# "React has detected a change in the order of Hook"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I encountered this issue while writing the test for the Auth Component. Not sure if its an issue with the way I write the test or an issue in the application itself. Below is the error.

```
         Previous render            Next render
         ------------------------------------------------------
      1. useState                   useState
      2. undefined                  useEffect
```

and  I see this message on the failed tests. "*Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.*"

When I added console statements on the useEffect, I see it's invoked only once.

Below is my Auth component.

```
const Auth: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
 const state = useConsoleState();
 const [problemType, setProblemType] = React.useState<ProblemTypeEnum>("TECH");
React.useEffect(() => {
    switch (props.supportType) {
      case "limit":
        setProblemType("LIMIT");
        break;
      case "account":
        setProblemType("ACCOUNT");
        break;
      default:
        setProblemType("TECH");
        break;
    }
  }, [props.supportType]);
};
const userId = getUserOcid(state.userProfile);
const cimsUserValidationResult = authApiCalls.callCims(!props.csi, props.csi, userId, problemType, state.homeRegionName);
```

and my test

```
describe("Auth tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
   const useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect");
   useEffect.mockImplementationOnce(f => f());
   authApiCalls.callCims = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      loading: false,
      response: {
        response: {
          ok: true,
        },
      },
    } as QueryResult<ValidationResponse>);
  });
  const runProblemTypeTest = (url: string, supportType: SupportType) => {
    window = Object.create(window);
    Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
      value: {
        href: url,
      },
      writable: true
    });
    mount(
      <Auth supportType=. {supportType}>
        <div>TestChild</div>
      </Authorization>
    );
    expect(authApiCalls.callCims).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      false,
      "1234",
      "test",
      supportType,
      "homeRegion"
    );
  };
  it("check problem type passed to validate when problem type absent in the url", () => {
    runProblemTypeTest("http://www.test.com", "tech");
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe add implementation of `useConsoleState()` to the question.

Comment: `jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');` is giving me all kind of strange behavior like "Rendered more hooks..." and "set state should be wrapped in `act(() => {...})` in axios response handling. When I modify Component to inject initial state in props, it works flawlessly. Amongst all ways to mock React useState or useEffect, there must be a pattern that keeps everything to behave normally. I'm still trying to figure how.